# Unlockable content tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Which would be preferred as a tag for unlockable content and items, unlockable or unlock?

I suggest unlockable for content, since unlock could then be used for "how do I unlock door x"

Comment: I immediately thought of DLC style unlockables when I read this question title.

Answer (score 4):

[unlockables] would probably be best. That way it does not, in fact, get confused with all matters of opening portals. It's unambiguous and well understood as a shorthand for unlockable content. That, and its easier to comprehend when seeing a question about "unlockables" than one about "unlock" (unlocking what?).

Comment: I would think that `[unlockable]` singular would make more sense. The pluralisation is a little confusing to me.

Comment: @Alastair I can understand that. It's a different between what terminology the gamers around you use. Some gamers use "unlockables" as a short hand for "unlockable content" as a whole plural noun. So, for example, "costumes" can be seen as "unlockable" (you can unlock different costumes) or as "unlockables" (costumes are some of the unlockable content). I think [unlockable] works just as well, and if it makes more sense then we definitely should use it over [unlockables].

Comment: Additionally, I'd suggest that [dlc] would be a reasonable replacement tag for [unlockable] to refer to dlc. And while I think in same ways [unlockable] makes more sense, what seems intuitive to me would be the plural version. However, the trend seems to be for singular tags so [unlockable] is what I'll use.

Comment: I've also gone through and retagged all [unlock] I saw to [unlockable].